# Novel about elves who can be mortally wounded by iron

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a book title about elves who can be mortally wounded by iron. The humans who interact with them in the fairy world...and then return to their own world, see the battle in the fairy world as swarms of insects. They help by placing a piece of iron in the way of the evil army.

I probably read it in the 1960s or early 1970s; the book was probably published around that time. I remember a great moment where an elf knight accidentally comes in contact with a piece of iron. He is disfigured and, because of the disfigurement, no longer wishes to live.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited those details into your question; if you remember any other details later on, please do the same. It helps us find the story if all of the identifying characteristics are contained in one place, rather than being spread among the comments

Comment: The idea that elves and fairies are allergic to iron is fairly common, both in folklore and in modern stories about elves.

Comment: {nods} The really unique bit is that the fairy world battles such up as swarms insects in the "real" world.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ColdIron is possibly relevant; it's a fairly widespread trope.